# Tomcat application deployment listener

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm wondering how can I listen for Tomcat web application deployments. I would like to have my listener invoked every time an application is undeployed or deployed from/to the container.

I already investigate a bit and found out that some listeners, i.e. `LifecycleListener` can be registered over JMX. But unfortunatelly this listener ins't enough for me since it triggers events just when Engine/Host/Context is in shutdown or startup process.

The same with `ContainerListener` that basically informs container shutdown and startup events.

So, my question basically is: **which interface shall I implement and how can I register it to tomcat in order to be notified every time a new application is deployed?**

Answer (score 1):

servlet context init/destroy

```
import org.apache.juli.logging.Log;
import org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AppContextListener.class);

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {
        logger.warn("AppContext Delete: " + e.getServletContext().getContextPath());
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
        logger.warn("AppContext Create: " + e.getServletContext().getContextPath());
    }

}
```

and put into tomcat/conf/web.xml

```
   <listener>
     <listener-class>AppContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```